# Efficient way to render a Modal in Next.js when you have a lot of data

Tags: next.js

I'm wondering how to efficiently render a modal in Next.js when the modal should display a lot more data than what I want to fetch on the page from which the modal is triggered.

Imagine you have a table with a lot (!) of rows. When you click on a row, a modal will open with more information.

[image: example]

I'm using the `page` directory (not the new `app` directory) so I can't fetch data inside a (modal) component. That leaves me with fetching the data on the page I guess.

Is fetching the data inside the modal, by using Next.js' new `app` directory, the right way to implement this?

I believe there's no way to implement the modal as a page (in which case I could use `getStaticProps` to pre-render all possible modals) AND also open that "Modal Page" while staying on the page that opened the Modal (ie. /admin in our example), but I'd love to be wrong.